# How to fire value signal events in LabVIEW with ActiveX?

Tags: activex, labview

I've been trying to access cluster variables. Recently I learned that you cant do so using .NET Network Shared Variables and I found that people usually do this via AcitveX.

Using ActiveX I am able to run any VI I want and change the values but most of the VIs that I am trying to access have UI Loops and Consumer Loops. Changing the value of a control manually, fires an event that is detected and leads to certain actions that I am interested in. After reading some old KBs I found out that with ActiveX one can't do that.

Is it the same in LabView 2015? In some forums people discussed creating a VI within the ActiveX program that fires the user events, a sort of a layer. Can someone share examples of such VIs? Are there any other work arounds?

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to access cluster variables. The current VIs only update variables when value signalling is captured by user events. ActiveX can't do value signals. I made VIs for reading and writing the cluster variables.

Comment: Where are you trying to access these clusters from - within the same LabVIEW application, a different LabVIEW application, or from external non-LabVIEW code? I assume it's the last of those as otherwise it doesn't make any sense to involve ActiveX or .NET, but a clearer description would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatic fire a signal event by using the property node -> value(Signaling)

Right click on the control in the block diagram, this can be found under: Create -> Property Node -> Value(Signaling).

Any value written to this node will generate a signal event for this specific control. You don't specifically need ActiveX to generate these events.

Comment: I think the asker wants to change the LabVIEW control from non-LabVIEW code, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

- You can fire events with property nodes (as already explained by @D.J. Klomp)
- You can capture and handle change events with event structures

This can be done even for single controls inside a cluster.

[image]